# Why Sum rule of probability has two different interpretations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was reading Pattern recognition by Bishop and the book have this section on probability there the sum rule was defined as follows

P(X=a) = $\sum_{Y} P(X,Y)$

Where X,Y are random variables and we are iterating through all the possible values of random variable Y. & let's say all possible values for random variable Y are as follows. Y = (A1,A2,A3.......An)

therefore

P(X=a) = P(X=a,Y=A1) + P(X=a,Y=A2) + ..... P(X=a,Y=An)

But in high school i learned a different version of sum rule of probability

P(X U Y) = P(X) + P(Y)

X,Y are mutually exclusive events

Now i am confused because i cannot see how both of these are related.

Comment: What values of $Y$ are we summing over in the first equation?

Comment: $X,Y$ mean different things in those two equations.  In the first, $Y$ spans a set of mutually exclusive events that cover all possibilities.  In the second, $Y$ just has to be mutually exclusive from $X$.

Comment: As a general rule:  don't write equations without saying what the unknowns represent.  In math, we use the same letters over and over again to mean very different things...there just aren't that many available symbols!  The fact that $x$ or $y$ appears in two equations doesn't mean that they are exactly the same thing.  You need context and definitions to be sure what things mean.

Comment: X & Y are random variables and we are summing all the possible value for the random variable Y while keeping X at a particular value. for which we want to find P(X=a) & we are iterating over all the possible values of Y

Comment: @lulu , sorry for that i will keep that in mind from next time but question is not based on usage of same symbol the thing is they both are formulae for Sum Rule and i cannot see if one is equivalent to other which they should be because they are formulae for same thing.

Comment: They are not the same formula and $X,Y$ simply don't mean the same thing in the two equations.  In the second, $P(X\cap Y)$ is assumed to be $0$ (else the formula is false).  In the first we certainly do not assume that.

Comment: @lulu so you are saying first formulae is also true for mutually exclusive sets but the second one is not ? if yes  then are those the only differences ??

Comment: What? That doesn't even make sense.  I think you are trying to avoid the hard work of properly writing out the definitions.  Edit your post to say exactly what you mean by $X,Y$.

Comment: I see the edit, and the first one looks good.  That's known as the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  Note the key point:  you are summing over all possibilities for $Y$.  There is, of course, no such sum in the second equation.  Now, edit the second equation to indicate what $X,Y$ mean in that case.

Comment: I agree, the edit looks strong.  The key point in the first equation is the sum...you are summing over all the distinct values $Y$ can hit.  In the second, the key point is that $X,Y$ are mutually exclusive...that isn't even possible in the first equation...well, assuming that $X,Y$ are possible events anyway.  That distinction makes a huge difference.

Comment: @lulu Could you please describe the distinction in little more details and the  prime question why they both are called sum rule in probability and how are they related

Comment: I have never heard the first one called the "sum rule".  as I linked to before, I'd call the first one the "law of total probability".  I wouldn't even call the second one the sum rule...I'd prefer to think of it as a special case of the formula for general $X,Y$...namely $P(X\cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$.  That's an instance of the more general principle of inclusion exclusion.  The formula you want follows when $P(X \cap Y)=0$.

Comment: @lulu first eqn is explicitly mentioned as sum rule in the book pattern recognition many times in fact it is summarised with a heading. Second one is infact called sum rule as i learned in high school and checked again on web and almost all sources i checked referred to it as Sum rule and as you mentioned it uses basic result from set theory for the case when events are disjoint.

Comment: That may be, in which case I'd say it was a case of  poor terminology.   I've seen the general formula $P(X\cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$ referred to as "the sum formula" (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#More_consequences) ) but personally I wouldn't.  But, in any case, I'd say the coincidence in terminology was just that and has no further meaning.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree that using the same terminology in different but related contexts is confusing at best and misleading at worst.  But, just to emphasize, these are not the same formula.  Both are very useful, but not the same.